# How to stop generating chunks in laravel mix

Tags: laravel, webpack

chunks are generating in web configuration - output

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'Vue')],
        alias: {
            styles: path.resolve(__dirname, './Content/SCSS/post-login-scss/scss/'),
            Vue: path.resolve(__dirname, './Vue'),
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './Vue')
        }
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: '/',
        chunkFilename: 'Scripts/app/js/chunks/[name].[chunkhash].js'
    },})
```

how to stop total generating any chunks

no findings found, want to stop generating chunks in laravel mix

Comment: Do you need the `output` part of `webpackConfig`?

Comment: Hi, how about setting `chunkFilename` to an empty string? like `chunkFilename: ''`

Comment: bundle and chunks are generating in laravel mix, but I need to try stop the generating the chunks and to check the performance.

I tried with chunkFilename: '' but it is not working

Comment: I'm using mix and no chunks are generated for me by default. Bundle is generated but only because I have explicitly used `mix.extract()`. I do not use  `webpackConfig` (but I also use React not Vue)